# (Invoke) Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, delegates

I was trying the [FileTransferManager](https://github.com/martinchrzan/FileTransferManager) library, which is used to transfer files/folders.
When I close my form while a copy is in progress *sometimes* I get this error:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'formMain'.

And the weird part as I mentioned earlier, I don't always get this error. Sometimes, the form closes without any issues.

I tried to check if formMain is actually disposed using `this.IsDisposed` at the time when the error occurs, but it always returns `false`. I even tried to put that check in the delegate but it didn't help.

Here's the StackTrace:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at DirCopyTest.formMain.SetProgressBarValue(ProgressBar progressBar, Int32 val) in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\FileTransferManagerDemo\formMain.cs:line 73
   at DirCopyTest.formMain.TransferProgressChanged(TransferProgress tp) in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\FileTransferManagerDemo\formMain.cs:line 60
   at IOExtensions.FileTransferManager.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CopyFileWithProgress>b__0(Int64 size, Int64 transferred, Int64 streamSize, Int64 bytesTransferred, UInt32 number, CopyProgressCallbackReason reason, IntPtr file, IntPtr destinationFile, IntPtr data)
```

This is the specific line that causes the error:

```
Invoke(new SetProgressBarCallback(SetProgressBarValue), new object[] { progressBar, val });
```

And here is the full code:

```
    CancellationTokenSource canceller;

    private async void buttonCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        canceller = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Action<TransferProgress> progress = new Action<TransferProgress>(TransferProgressChanged);

        await FileTransferManager.CopyWithProgressAsync(source, destination, progress, canceller.Token, false, true);
    }

    void TransferProgressChanged(TransferProgress tp)
    {
        if (!canceller.IsCancellationRequested)
           SetProgressBarValue(progressBar1, (int)tp.Percentage);
    }

    delegate void SetProgressBarCallback(ProgressBar progressBar, int val);

    private void SetProgressBarValue(ProgressBar progressBar, int val)
    {
        if (progressBar.InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(new SetProgressBarCallback(SetProgressBarValue), new object[] { progressBar, val });
        else
            progressBar.Value = val;  
    }

    private void formMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        canceller.Cancel();
    }
```

Comment: _"I tried to check if formMain is actually disposed using this.IsDisposed"_ - where did you check this? In the `else`? Or before you `Invoke`?

Comment: @John I tried it in both cases, and neither helped.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a good old-fashioned *race condition* between

```
if (!canceller.IsCancellationRequested)
```

and

```
progressBar.Value = val;
```

You could do a final check just before the later, it will shorten the window but not mitigate it.

```
if (!canceller.IsCancellationRequested)
   progressBar.Value = val;
```

And / or you could just wrap the `Value = val` update in a `try` and `catch` on `ObjectDisposedException` and write-it-off

Comment: I'm afraid the first suggestion didn't help. As for the later, I knew I could do that but it felt like a cop-out so I was wondering if there was a proper solution, but I'm starting to think there isn't.

Comment: @root how fast is this bar updating?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that, but it's being updated every time `TransferProgressChanged` is triggered.

Comment: @root i am very surprised `if (!canceller.IsCancellationRequested)
   progressBar.Value = val;` doesn't help, however if the message pump is getting smashed it likely wont. either way, you cant ever guarantee it wont throw, unless you hold the form open until you are sure everything has caught up